# Graph of a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ . Prove that if $f$ is continuous, then the graph of $f$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m = \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$

any ideas on how to commence this problem?

Comment: Note: A more general variant of this questions seems to be [Is the graph Gf .. a closed subset of X×Y?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108709/is-the-graph-g-f-x-fx-in-x-times-y-x-in-x-a-closed-subset-of-x).

Comment: Can you at least start? Say take a sequence of points in the graph that converges to a point in $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^m?$

Comment: See my answer to this question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505745/is-a-vector-field-a-closed-map/1505755#1505755. The same proof works here.

Comment: [Brian's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/108721/86776) seems a reasonable approach. He goes for showing that the complement of the graph is open.

Answer (score 1):

Take $(x_n,f(x_n))\in G(f)$ auch that $(x_k,f(x_k))\to (x,y)$. So you have $x_k\to x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and by continuity of $f$ you have $y=\lim_kf(x_k)=f(x)$. Therefore $(x,y)=(x,f(x))\in G(f)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the projections $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$.

The graph of $f$ is

$$(\pi_2-f\circ \pi_1)^{-1}(0),$$

hence closed.